# UICollectionVIew: Animate cells as they scroll in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, core-animation, uicollectionview

I would like items in my `UICollectionView` to animate in to view as the user scrolls through the list (I am using a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`).

I specify the position in the Layout Manager, what I would like to be able to do is to also specify an initial transform and have that applied in an animation at the correct time (when the cell first appears on screen). To see the effect I mean, check out the Google Plus app on iOS. Ideally a different transform depending on the location of the cell.

I can't seem to find a way to find out when a cell is displayed (no equivalent of `willDisplayCell` as there is on `UITableView`) or any pointers on where to go for this.

Any suggestions?

You can just about make out the animation in Google Plus in this screen shot:
[image: Example in the Google Plus App]

Also, take a look at iPhoto on the iPad. I don't know if they're using a UIcollectionView (probably not, as it worked on iOS5) but this is the sort if effect I'm looking for, the photos appear to fly in from the right.

Comment: Hey did u ended up getting an answer for that ? i'm trying to implement the same behaviour, will appreciate your help.

Comment: No, sorry - I ended up using a standard scroll view.

Comment: @JackKapow, I posted an answer below which might be useful.

Comment: @JackKapow I probably won't have a chance to test this for a while, so if you try this and it works, let me know here and I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok I checked it ! works perfectly thanks allot!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can achieve this effect independently of having a custom layout.

The animation code should go inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

When a cell is dequeued, its `frame` will be set to what is specified in your layout. You can store it in a temporary variable as the final `frame` for the cell. You can then set the `cell.frame` to a initial position outside the screen, and then animate towards the desired final position. Something along the lines of:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect finalCellFrame = cell.frame;
    //check the scrolling direction to verify from which side of the screen the cell should come.
    CGPoint translation = [collectionView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:collectionView.superview];
    if (translation.x > 0) {
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(finalCellFrame.origin.x - 1000, - 500.0f, 0, 0);
    } else {
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(finalCellFrame.origin.x + 1000, - 500.0f, 0, 0);
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
        cell.frame = finalCellFrame;
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

The code above will animate cells on a horizontal `UICollectionView`, coming from the top of the screen, and from either side, depending on the scrolling direction. You could also check the current `indexPath` to have cells animating from different positions on more complicated layouts, as well as animate other properties along with the frame, or apply a transform.

Comment: Hey ! thanks ! I played with it a bit and for now it looks great ! I'll let you know if I find any problems , Thanks allot!!!!

Comment: Do you have an idea how to make it only animate once ? i mean when i scroll down only for the first time i want it to animate - and then i want only new cells to animate (exactly like in google +)

Comment: I know what you mean. In Google +, what is probably happening is they are animating when new content is inserted into the CollectionView datasource. To prevent animating again on scrolling, I suppose you'd need to store an array of flags and set their values for each indexPath that has been animated. When dequeuing a cell for a given indexPath, you'd check that array to see if you should animate.

Comment: Yeah I did something like you said , It works great ! actually no need to to animate when new data arrives to the data source because i'm using dequeing of cells - the cells are actually loaded while scrolling so i just keep track of cells which were already loaded. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cezar Super cool! Thanks for that! I was looking where to put it in `UICollectionViewLayout initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:`, but it's now looks so obvious it should be where you said.

Answer (score 5):

You need to override `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` in your collection view layout. Here you can set any attribute on the layout attributes item (including the transform) which will be animated to the actual attributes after the cell has appeared.

If the standard layout attributes object doesn't give you enough options, you can subclass it, add extra attributes, and override `applyLayoutAttributes:` on your cell to pick up the extra properties.

This will only work when you are adding cells to the collection view.

To have transforms applied to cells as you scroll down the collection view, I'd look at applying them either directly to the cell (at `cellForItem`...) or in the layout attributes, perhaps a property called `initialTransform`. When applying the layout attributes to the cell, you'd check the `initialTransform`, apply it, then set it to identity, then trigger an animation to go to the identity transform, so it would only be applied when the cell was first scrolled onto the screen. I haven't implemented anything like this, it's just a guess as to how I would do it.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint here it only gets called when the screen rotates. The header comments seem to indicate it this too. Is there something else I need to configure?
I am subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: It should be called when adding items to the view or when scrolling.

Comment: According to the docs this method is called when the data changes, or when the collection view needs to redraw, not when scrolling - unless I am doing something wrong? Can you confirm you get this callback fired as you scroll?

Quote
"**When the data in the collection view changes and items are to be inserted or deleted, the collection view asks its layout object to update the layout information.**"
From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You're absolutely right, I apologise. The method in my answer will only help if you are adding cells into the collection view, my comment about scrolling was wrong. As a first step I'd look at applying the transform in cellForItemAtIndexPath, you may have to do this as a property on the cell and apply it in applyLayoutAttributes (after super has done its work).

Comment: Thanks - thought I was going mad  :o)

Answer (score 3):

As Marc mentioned in a comment, that he ended up using a scroll view I want to show how to do it with a standard table view. It is not the same effect as seen in google+ but could be adapted easily.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static CGFloat duration = .5;
    static NSUInteger xOffset = 50;
    static NSUInteger yOffset = 200;
    if(scrollDirection == STAScrollDirectionDown && lastAnimatedIndex < indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x - xOffset, cell.frame.origin.y+yOffset, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                         animations:^{
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + xOffset, cell.frame.origin.y - yOffset, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            lastAnimatedIndex = indexPath.row;
        }];
    }
}
```

Just before the cell is being displayed we assign an offset (and possibly a rotation) to each cell and than we animate it back to the previous settings.

---

a little more exciting example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, .0, 0.5, 0.5);
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0.8;
    cell.contentView.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.contentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                     animations:^{
                         cell.contentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                         cell.contentView.alpha = 1;
                         cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of a `cellWillAppear`

Comment: Sorry I' meant cellWillDisplay I just confused the name with viewWillAppear, check this image : http://postimg.org/image/a2g02xgbl/

Comment: Create a new question, post your code, describe what you want to achieve and what you see instead.