# How to programmatically scroll through a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a collection view in my view. In the cells are image views and it has one section.

I now want to scroll programmatically through the images. I want the animation to happen endless so it starts with item one after reaching item 10.

It also would be helpful if you provide some method where to put animations like the cells getting bigger after getting programmatically swiped in from right.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two methods that could help you achieve this:

```
func scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath,
        atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition,
                animated animated: Bool)
```

or

```
func setContentOffset(contentOffset: CGPoint,
         animated animated: Bool)
```

Both are on `UICollectionView` so you can use whatever seems more convenient. To create a custom animation for this however is more difficult. A quick solution depending on what you need could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664747/1949494).

**Swift 4, iOS 11:**

```
// UICollectionView method
func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
                  at scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition,  
                  animated: Bool)

// UIScrollView method
func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool)
```

Comment: Both methods would work in the way that they are scrolling but have you an idea to let it scroll from item 1 to 2, to 3, to 4 and after 10 to 1 and that as a uniformly accelerated motion that happens endless. I mean that the things happening when you scroll with your finger happen programmatically.

Comment: Then you could use a `NSTimer` to perform a repeated task and  call `setContentOffset` with a value incremented after each call.

Comment: Is it possible that the timer fires after the completion of scrolling to a certain item? Sth. like waiting for completion and then fire?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you do not need that if you scroll without animation and the timer loop is really small and also the value you increment with is small it should look smooth.

Comment: So I need to measure the time it takes to perform the scrolling.

Comment: No, just play with the time and the scroll value you change each time until you get the desired effect.

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 5**

Based on [Mr.Bean's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5242864/mr-bean) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337048/2122149), here is an elegant way using UICollectionView extension:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func scrollToNextItem() {
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x + self.bounds.size.width))
        self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
    }

    func scrollToPreviousItem() {
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x - self.bounds.size.width))
        self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
    }

    func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffset, y: self.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now you can use it wherever you want:

```
collectionView.scrollToNextItem()
collectionView.scrollToPreviousItem()
```

Comment: should check `guard contentOffset <= self.contentSize.width - self.bounds.size.width else { return }` before ScrollToNextItem.

Answer (score 15):

By far this is the best approach i have encountered, the trick is to scroll to the frame which is containing next objects. Please refer the code

```
/* -------------- display previous friends action ----------------*/
@IBAction func actionPreviousFriends(_ sender: Any) {

    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - collectionBounds.size.width))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

/* -------------- display next friends action ----------------*/
@IBAction func actionNextFriends(_ sender: Any) {

    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionBounds.size.width))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {

    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.collectionView.contentOffset.y ,width : self.collectionView.frame.width,height : self.collectionView.frame.height)
    self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this UICollectionView extension (**Swift 4.2**)

```
        extension UICollectionView {

        func scrollToNextItem() {
            let scrollOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x + self.bounds.size.width))
            self.scrollToFrame(scrollOffset: scrollOffset)
        }

        func scrollToPreviousItem() {
            let scrollOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x - self.bounds.size.width))
            self.scrollToFrame(scrollOffset: scrollOffset)
        }

        func scrollToFrame(scrollOffset : CGFloat) {
            guard scrollOffset <= self.contentSize.width - self.bounds.size.width else { return }
            guard scrollOffset >= 0 else { return }
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollOffset, y: self.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And the usage will be like

```
yourCollectionView.scrollToNextItem()
yourCollectionView.scrollToPreviousItem()
```