# iOS: UITableView acceleration slows down when doing animations in willDisplayCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, core-animation

**LATEST EDIT:**
After some more experimentation I'm convinced that I'm running into a touch handling issue.
I created a custom cell with a subview that fills half the width of the content view. I'm animating that subview instead of the content view.

[image: Cell with Half view]

Scrolling the tableview while touching the right side of the cell works normally.
Scrolling the tableview on the left side of the cell (where the animating view is) causes lag.

**EDIT:**
In the end I'm trying to do an animation similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764991/uicollectionview-animate-cells-as-they-scroll-in).
The accepted answer in that question has the same problem I'm asking about.
The code below is the simplest one that reproduces the issue.

Doing the animation in `dequeCellForIndexPath` instead of `willDisplayCell` makes no difference.

When doing animations in `willDisplayCell`, table view scrolling animation slows down. When you try to scroll fast in the tableview, the scrolling loses acceleration.

Some sample code that reproduces the issue:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        cell.contentView.layer.opacity = 0.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            cell.contentView.layer.opacity = 1.0
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5000
    }
}
```

The problem gets worst when the cell's height is big.

Is there anyway to avoid this, or some better function to do cell animations in?

Related: [Blogpost on doing animations like this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76024/swift-table-view-animations-tutorial-drop-cards)

**EDIT 2:**
GIFs illustrating the issue:

In all 3 cases I'm scrolling as fast as I can on my phone.

With an animation in willDisplayCell I reach row 60

[image: Using Animation]

Without an animation I reach row 400+

[image: Normal Scrolling]

With a random delay between 0 - 0.3 seconds in willDisplayCell, blocking the main queue, I reach row 120

[image: Laggy Scrolling]

I guess there's an issue with touch handling somewhere.

Even [the library I use to visualize how fast I'm scrolling](https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer), breaks when using animations in `willDisplayCell`.

Comment: "Doctor doctor it hurts when I do like this!" "So don't do like that!" Seriously — adding animation to what's already happening when scrolling is a _terrible_ idea.

Comment: @matt Plenty of apps have custom animations for cell appearance. UITableView animates cell insertion / deletion. Could you explain why animating a cell appearing on screen is such a TERRIBLE idea ?

Comment: Because it overpowers the render tree and the scrolling stutters — as you yourself have said.

Comment: Rendering is not the bottleneck here. If I call `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)`, in the willDisplayCell method, the table lags very badly, but doesn't lose acceleration during scrolling.

Comment: You don't have any idea what the bottleneck is unless you've used Instruments to find out. And I see no evidence that you have done so.

Comment: @matt I have used instruments to profile it. With no animation the FPS is 59-60. With animation the FPS gets a bit lower but never below 56. CPU usage with no animation is ~30%. CPU usage with animation is ~8% (lower than with animations turned off). I suspect something else is causing this weird behaviour, or I'm grossly misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone 6S and an iPhone 5. The scrolling behaves in the same way on both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(..)` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. I tried the code below and scroll performance looks fine to me. I also added `cell.contentView.layer.removeAllAnimations()` to cancel animations after the cell disappeared.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? TableViewCell else { fatalError("where's my cell") }
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 300
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5000
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.layer.opacity = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        cell.contentView.layer.opacity = 1.0
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Actually I see what you're saying now, it's still a little choppy when decelerating. It's still best to dequeue instead of creating a new cell though :)

Comment: thanks for the response. Yeah, I know it's best deque instead of re-create but for this issue it doesn't make any difference. It's like the tableview is ignoring touches or something. You have to scroll fast to notice the issue.. you keep scrolling but the table view doesn't accelerate like it normally does instead it smoothly decelerates.

Answer (score 1):

So, you should certainly dequeue cells rather than recreate them all the time. In your test that won't make so much of a difference but as your cells get more complex it will.

Also, you need to think about when your animations make sense to use, and how big the animations should be. There's a reason that stock animations on collection views are only for items being added - because it's an effective use of animation. In general, when the user is scrolling up for instance, the items aren't new so any animation on the cell scrolling into view is a confusing paradigm.

Now, when scrolling down I can see why you might want to animate in. In this case you need to consider the scroll speed - if you're scrolling then the animation is hard / impossible to see, so there's no point in doing it...

So, track the scroll speed. In the simple option, if you're scrolling faster than some threshold speed then just don't animate. In the complex option modulate the size of the animation for the scroll speed so slow scrolling still has the majority of the animation and faster scrolling tones down the animation until you hit that threshold and you turn the animation off all together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please check out my latest edit? Very good idea idea with disabling animations after a certain threshold speed, I will use that.

Comment: In my real project I am of course dequeueing cells. Animations are only happening once per cell when scrolling down.  Also the actual animations are more complex than simple fade in / fade out. The example I'm giving here is the simplest code that reproduces my issue so I omitted a lot of details.

Comment: I don't know, but i could understand if there was some issue with hit detection and animating views, though less so for opacity animations compared to positional. It's probably worth creating a radar with your sample project and seeing what feedback you get.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, first you have to dequeue a cell rather than initializing a new one each time.

If you're using `AutoLayout` for layout of your cells, i recommend remove it **if nothing else worked**. (It's a great feature, but it also takes lots of cpu time).

But my solution would be a workaround and do not use `UIViewAnimation`. use `UIScrollViewDelegate` instead. in `scrollViewDidScroll` method, take visible cells of the `tableView` and set alpha of last cell by calculating it's distance from bottom of screen directly without any animations.