# Swift UICollectionView Cell Transition Effect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I use full frame UICollectionView as PageViewController. I want to add transition style when passing next/previous item. Normally cells are following each other start points and end points but I want to give an effect that "CrossFade" effect like in this library - https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout .

But I want to keep the first cell in the backgorund and second cell cover the first cell "like lay a sheet" .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I didnt try anything just show normal behaviour. I want to start but I dont know where I start

Comment: Well, you could at least look at how that library does that. Also, maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764991/uicollectionview-animate-cells-as-they-scroll-in) could give you a sense of direction. Make sure to take a look at this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Answer (score 0):

use collectionView custom flow layout for that and implement the required transition.

Comment: give an example. I know I have to use flow layout

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest  - : hope this one help you to understant how it works

Comment: sorry this is a irrelevant example